# Checking the application loading speed on Android device

Tags: android, flutter, performance

I have some web development experiences and today I started learning Flutter.
I made a really basic app, that displays a time in different countries.
It loads very fast, but I want to see how long it takes to open.
I found a lot of tutorials about how to do this but I don't understand them.
I want to compare the results of my app with results of other apps on my phone,
so if you know some apps to test load speed pls send me a link or explain how to do it in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is time to initial display.
[Time to initial display](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#retrieve-TTID)

`ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.myexample/.StartupTiming: +3s534ms (total +1m22s643ms)`

Open your logs and filter by `Displayed`

I dunno what the flutter counterpart is but since it's an activity you're opening it should be the same.

The other way is using Systrace and Perfetto.

[Medium Article on systrace and Perfetto](https://narendranathchatterjee.medium.com/how-long-does-it-take-just-systrace-and-perfetto-it-8a48f19eb503)